# jQuery Vertical Slide Out menu using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've coded a vertical menu in which the `sub-items` are shown when the mouse is hovered on the parent.
The HTML structure is:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Continents</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Europe</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Asia</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Africa</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Places</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Place1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Place2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Oceans</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Pacific</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Atlantic</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Initially only `nav li` elements are shown. But when a user hovers on the `nav li a`, the successive child elements are shown. I succeeded in doing this when there was only one `ul` under the `initial li` elements. But [as you'll see in my HTML structure above], I require a 2nd nested `ul` in the 1st `li` branch.

My javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#nav > li > a').hover(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
                        $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
                        $(this).next().slideToggle();
                        $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            });         
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you rquire this kind of output: http://jsfiddle.net/uNKvu/

```
$('#nav li').hover(function () {
    $('> ul',this).slideToggle();
});
```